# How can I create new array from this JSON response?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, foreach

I am really struggling to create a new array from this response, I don't know where and how to start or to do it:

```
{
    "fruits": [
        {
            "name": "Bananas",
            "pieces": 2469429
        },
        {
            "name": "Oranges",
            "pieces": 1576890
        },
        {
            "name": "Lemons",
            "pieces": 5645318
        }
    ],
    "size": [
        {
            "size": "5000-10,000 eaters",
            "pieces": 17008533
        },
        {
            "size": "100-500 eaters",
            "pieces": 23473914
        },
        {
            "size": "10,001+ eaters",
            "pieces": 68086139
        }
    ],
    "SizeAndFruit": [
        {
            "size": "100-500 eaters",
            "pieces": 226636,
            "name": "Bananas"
        },        
        {
            "size": "5000-10,000 eaters",
            "pieces": 249004,
            "name": "Bananas"
        },
        {
            "size": "10,001+ eaters",
            "pieces": 727829,
            "name": "Bananas"
        },
        {
            "size": "100-500 eaters",
            "pieces": 416310,
            "name": "Lemons"
        },
        {
            "size": "5000-10,000 eaters",
            "pieces": 488711,
            "name": "Lemons"
        },
        {
            "size": "10,001+ eaters",
            "pieces": 2340652,
            "name": "Lemons"
        },
        {
            "size": "100-500 eaters",
            "pieces": 217037,
            "name": "Oranges"
        },
        {
            "size": "5000-10,000 eaters",
            "pieces": 71779,
            "name": "Oranges"
        },
        {
            "size": "10,001+ eaters",
            "pieces": 201729,
            "name": "Oranges"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get this new structure/array:

```
{
    "newArray": [
    {
        "name": "Bananas",
        "totalResults": 2469429,
        "sortedResults": [
            {
                "size": "100-500 eaters",
                "pieces": 226636
            },
            {
                "size": "5000-10,000 eaters",
                "pieces": 249004
            },
            {
                "size": "10,001+ eaters",
                "pieces": 727829
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Oranges",
        "totalResults": 1576890,
        "sortedResults": [
            {
                "size": "100-500 eaters",
                "pieces": 217037
            },
            {
                "size": "5000-10,000 eaters",
                "pieces": 71779
            },
            {
                "size": "10,001+ eaters",
                "pieces": 201729
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Lemons",
        "totalResults": 5645318,
        "sortedResults": [
            {
                "size": "100-500 eaters",
                "pieces": 416310
            },
            {
                "size": "5000-10,000 eaters",
                "pieces": 488711
            },
            {
                "size": "10,001+ eaters",
                "pieces": 2340652
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

How can I make for each fruit to add all sizes as subarray from the sizeAndFruit as the example above? After that each fruit has to be row in a table, that's why I need to get this new array? Please let me know if you have any suggestions or any extra questions I will be glad to explain more if needed. Thank you very much!

---

Edit for David:
How about if we always order them by size?
Here is the snippet: pastecode.io/s/t82n19x4 so when the order is like this. So, to order them by size as it is now on David's reply, because if these are mixed then they order as they go instead by 100-500 5001-10000 10,000+ they go 10.000+ 100-500 5001-1000, etc.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below codes reads your inputs and turns it into your desired output (including sorting by `size`):

```php
<?php

$inputContents = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/input.json');
$inputJson = json_decode($inputContents);

$out = [];

foreach ($inputJson->fruits as $fruit) {
    $out[] = [
        'name' => $fruit->name,
        'totalResults' => $fruit->pieces,
        'sortedResults' => [],
    ];
}

foreach ($inputJson->SizeAndFruit as $entry) {
    $newEntry = [
        'size' => $entry->size,
        'pieces' => $entry->pieces,
    ];

    foreach ($out as &$fruit) {
        if ($fruit['name'] === $entry->name) {
            $fruit['sortedResults'][] = $newEntry;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Get a number of the size from the provided string.
 * 
 * @param string $size
 * 
 * @return int|null
 */
function sizeStringToNumber(string $size): ?int
{
    $sizes = [
        '100-500 eaters' => 100,
        '5000-10,000 eaters' => 5000,
        '10,001+ eaters' => 10000,
    ];

    if (isset($sizes[$size])) {
        return $sizes[$size];
    }

    throw new \Exception('Unknown size: ' . $size);
}

/**
 * Sort the `sortedResults` array by `size` in ascending order.
 */
foreach ($out as &$fruit) {
    usort($fruit['sortedResults'], function ($a, $b) {
        $aSize = sizeStringToNumber($a['size']);
        $bSize = sizeStringToNumber($b['size']);
        return $aSize <=> $bSize;
    });
}


$outArray = [
    'newArray' => $out,
];
$outJson = json_encode($outArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

print_r($outJson);
```

Prints as:

```json
{
    "newArray": [
        {
            "name": "Bananas",
            "totalResults": 2469429,
            "sortedResults": [
                {
                    "size": "100-500 eaters",
                    "pieces": 226636
                },
                {
                    "size": "5000-10,000 eaters",
                    "pieces": 249004
                },
                {
                    "size": "10,001+ eaters",
                    "pieces": 727829
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Oranges",
            "totalResults": 1576890,
            "sortedResults": [
                {
                    "size": "100-500 eaters",
                    "pieces": 217037
                },
                {
                    "size": "5000-10,000 eaters",
                    "pieces": 71779
                },
                {
                    "size": "10,001+ eaters",
                    "pieces": 201729
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Lemons",
            "totalResults": 5645318,
            "sortedResults": [
                {
                    "size": "100-500 eaters",
                    "pieces": 416310
                },
                {
                    "size": "5000-10,000 eaters",
                    "pieces": 488711
                },
                {
                    "size": "10,001+ eaters",
                    "pieces": 2340652
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much David! How about if the "sizeAndFruit" are not in order, for example they are mixed like this:

Comment: They are in the order of your output specification, you want them to be ordered by the `pieces` value in ascending order?

Comment: Thank you very much David! How about if the "sizeAndFruit" are not in order, for example they are mixed like this:

Comment: Sorry had trouble pasting the snippet, not sure where can I paste the snippet?

Comment: You can extend your question.

Comment: Here is the snippet: https://pastecode.io/s/t82n19x4 so when the order is like this to order them by size as it is now, because if these are mixed then they order as they go instead by 100-500 5001-10000 10,000+ they go 10.000+ 100-500 5001-1000 etc etc.

Comment: Please add that to your question.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, I have edited the initial question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241804/discussion-between-david-wolf-and-ifkas).

Comment: Thank you David Wolf! This is the answer that catches it all, kudos to you!!